# Detect operator support with decltype/SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, decltype

A (somewhat) outdated [article](http://blog.think-async.com/2009/07/user-friendly-compile-errors-for.html) explores ways to use `decltype` along with SFINAE to detect if a type supports certain operators, such as `==` or `<`.

Here's example code to detect if a class supports the `<` operator:

```
template <class T>
struct supports_less_than
{
    static auto less_than_test(const T* t) -> decltype(*t < *t, char(0))
    { }

    static std::array<char, 2> less_than_test(...) { }

    static const bool value = (sizeof(less_than_test((T*)0)) == 1);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << supports_less_than<std::string>::value << endl;
}
```

This outputs `true`, since of course `std::string` supports the `<` operator.  However, if I try to use it with a class that *doesn't* support the `<` operator, I get a compiler error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘* t < * t’
```

So SFINAE is not working here.  I tried this on GCC 4.4 and GCC 4.6, and both exhibited the same behavior.  So, is it possible to use SFINAE in this manner to detect whether a type supports certain expressions?

Comment: We don't need to use `c++0x` for checking if `operator <` function exists in the class. We can simply templatize that function for generic overload and use its size for negative logic. See my answer below.

Comment: For those seeking a portable prepackaged solution for this, there is `template <class Lhs, class Rhs=Lhs, class Ret=dont_care>
struct has_less : public true_type-or-false_type {};` in `#include<boost/type_traits/has_less.hpp>`. Documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_less.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make your less_than_test function a template, since SFINAE stands for Substitution Failure Is Not An Error and there's no template function that can fail selection in your code.

```
template <class T>
struct supports_less_than
{
    template <class U>
    static auto less_than_test(const U* u) -> decltype(*u < *u, char(0))
    { }

    static std::array<char, 2> less_than_test(...) { }

    static const bool value = (sizeof(less_than_test((T*)0)) == 1);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << supports_less_than<std::string>::value << endl;
}
```

Comment: But this code still throws error, if a class doesn't have `operator <`. Questioner has just mentioned only compiled code. And I think you have pasted the same.

Comment: I posted a corrected and full version of the code below (because I was loathe to edit your post so thoroughly). You can use it to correct your example, and in this case I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @iammilind: see my answer, it does work, as tested on ideone at http://ideone.com/a68WO

Comment: Very nice, uncovoluted code (also, finally someone demonstrating a __useful__ no-crap application of the comma operator!). Interestingly, it seems to work perfectly well for all builtin types and most of the standard library, as well as for all global `operator<(T,T)`. However it _does not seem to work_ for in-class `operator<(T)`, reporting `false` (using gcc 4.6).

Answer (score 21):

In C++11 the shortest most general solution I found was this one:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class = decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>() )> 
std::true_type  supports_less_than_test(const T&);
std::false_type supports_less_than_test(...);

template<class T> using supports_less_than = decltype(supports_less_than_test(std::declval<T>()));

#include<iostream>
struct random_type{};
int main(){
    std::cout << supports_less_than<double>::value << std::endl; // prints '1'
    std::cout << supports_less_than<int>::value << std::endl; // prints '1'
    std::cout << supports_less_than<random_type>::value << std::endl; // prints '0'
}
```

Works with `g++ 4.8.1` and `clang++ 3.3`

---

**A more general solution for arbitrary operators (UPDATE 2014)**

There is a more general solution that exploits the fact that all built-in operators are also accessible (and posibly specialized) through STD operator wrappers, such as `std::less` (binary) or `std::negate` (unary).

```
template<class F, class... T, typename = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T>()...))> 
std::true_type  supports_test(const F&, const T&...);
std::false_type supports_test(...);

template<class> struct supports;
template<class F, class... T> struct supports<F(T...)> 
: decltype(supports_test(std::declval<F>(), std::declval<T>()...)){};
```

This can be used in a quite general way, especially in C++14, where type deduction is delayed to the operator wrapper call ("transparent operators").

For binary operators it can be used as:

```
#include<iostream>
struct random_type{};
int main(){
    std::cout << supports<std::less<>(double, double)>::value << std::endl; // '1'
    std::cout << supports<std::less<>(int, int)>::value << std::endl; // '1'
    std::cout << supports<std::less<>(random_type, random_type)>::value << std::endl; // '0'
}
```

For unary operators:

```
#include<iostream>
struct random_type{};
int main(){
    std::cout << supports<std::negate<>(double)>::value << std::endl; // '1'
    std::cout << supports<std::negate<>(int)>::value << std::endl; // '1'
    std::cout << supports<std::negate<>(random_type)>::value << std::endl; // '0'
}
```

(With the C++11 standard library is a bit more complicated because there is no failure on instatiating `decltype(std::less<random_type>()(...))` even if there is no operation defined for `random_type`, one can implement manually transparent operators in C++11, that are standard in C++14)

The syntax is quite smooth. I hope something like this is adopted in the standard.

---

**Two extensions:**

1) It works to detect raw-function applications:

```
struct random_type{};
random_type fun(random_type x){return x;}
int main(){
    std::cout << supports<decltype(&fun)(double)>::value << std::endl; // '0'
    std::cout << supports<decltype(&fun)(int)>::value << std::endl; // '0'
    std::cout << supports<decltype(&fun)(random_type)>::value << std::endl; // '1'
}
```

2) It can additionally detect if the result is convertible/comparable to a certain type, in this case `double < double` is supported but a compile-time false will be returned because the result is not the specified one.

```
std::cout << supports<std::equal_to<>(std::result_of<std::less<>(double, double)>::type, random_type)>::value << std::endl; // '0'
```

<s>*Note: I just tried to compile the code with C++14 in http://melpon.org/wandbox/ and it didn't work. I think there is a problem with transparent operators (like `std::less<>`) in that implementation (clang++ 3.5 c++14), since when I implement my own `less<>` with automatic deduction it works well.*</s>

Comment: +1: This is my personal favorite. It's short and works well. Note that the `c++` executable is actually an alias for `g++`, if you're on Linux.

Comment: Any chance to apply this to the member access `operator->`?

Comment: @Walter, what do you mean? `template<class T, class = decltype(std::declval<T>()->() )> 
std::true_type  supports_arrow_test(const T&);
std::false_type supports_arrow_test(...);`

Answer (score 6):

This is C++0x, we don't need `sizeof`-based tricks any more... ;-]

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace supports
{
    namespace details
    {
        struct return_t { };
    }

    template<typename T>
    details::return_t operator <(T const&, T const&);

    template<typename T>
    struct less_than : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        !std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<T const&>() < std::declval<T const&>()),
            details::return_t
        >::value
    > { };
}
```

(This is based on iammilind's answer, but doesn't require that `T`'s `operator<` return-type be a different size than `long long` and doesn't require that `T` be default-constructable.)

Comment: FYI, there's also `std::declval<T>()` that you can use instead of your own `details::make<T>()`.

Comment: @pyrtsa : Ah, indeed -- I tend to forget about `declval` since it's not in VC++ 2010. I'll edit.

Comment: @ldjarn: For those of us who use VC++ 2010, do you mind putting back the details::make<T>() version too?

Comment: @Dilip : You should be able to view my answer's edit history and see the original code.

Answer (score 3):

Below simple code satisfies your requirement (if you don't want compile error):

```
namespace supports {
  template<typename T>  // used if T doesn't have "operator <" associated
  const long long operator < (const T&, const T&);

  template <class T>
  struct less_than {
    T t;
    static const bool value = (sizeof(t < t) != sizeof(long long));
  };  
}
```

Usage:

```
supports::less_than<std::string>::value ====> true;  // ok
supports::less_than<Other>::value ====> false;  // ok: no error
```

[Note: If you want compile error for classes not having `operator <` than it's very easy to generate with very few lines of code.]

Comment: Technically, if a type overloads `operator <` and happens to yield a type the same size as a `long long` [or if `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(long long)`], this could yield a false negative.  In such a case, the overload probably isn't being used as a comparator anyhow, but its worth being aware of.

Comment: This also requires that a type be default constructable. These are not only issues worth being aware of, they're also completely trivial to fix...

Comment: @ildjarn, why down vote, I checked my code. It works even if type is not default constructible. Can you point out the issue please ?

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using, but no compiler should allow `static` member initializations to use non-`static` data members -- how would it know which instance's data member to use? The code is clearly nonsensical.

Comment: @ildijarn, I am using ubuntu g++ and I have checked this code with `-std=c++0x` also. Both are working perfectly fine. Also note that, we are not exactly "using" data members; we are just instantiating the function instance (i.e. `operator <`). Does this code not working for your compiler or giving wrong result ? (except that `long long` stuff)

Comment: @ildjarn: It's an unevaluated context, so it doesn't need to know what instance, only the type.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12508771/103167

Answer (score 0):

@xDD is indeed correct, though his example is slightly erroneous.

This compiles on ideone:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Support {}; bool operator<(Support,Support) { return false; }
struct DoesNotSupport{};

template <class T>
struct supports_less_than
{
  template <typename U>
  static auto less_than_test(const U* u) -> decltype(*u < *u, char(0))
  { }

  static std::array<char, 2> less_than_test(...) { }

  static const bool value = (sizeof(less_than_test((T*)0)) == 1);
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << supports_less_than<Support>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha <<
     supports_less_than<DoesNotSupport>::value << std::endl;
}
```

And results in:

```
true
false
```

See [it here](http://ideone.com/a68WO) in action.

The point is that SFINAE only applies to template **functions**.

Comment: @Matthieu, even my answer also works properly. But OP has decided to accept the first answer. :)

Comment: @iammilind: yours work by side-effect, since it relies on a specific size for the return type of `operator<`. I admit that it should work in all practical cases :)

Comment: I fail to see an obvious different to the code in my answer. Do you mean the added include directives? If so, I left those out because they were left out in the question as well.

Comment: @xDD: If I remember correctly there are two things: `endl` is missing the `std::` qualifier and it's great when demonstrating a trait predicate to show both alternatives. The second does not prevent compilation, obviously.

Comment: I only corrected the OP's code, as he asked. It's likely just a snippet of a larger file and that explains the missing includes, and he is probably using the std namespace.

Comment: @xDD: probably using the std namespace, unfortunately :) Anyway the goal was just to provide a minimum compilable example to thwart the "it does not compile" comments.