# Can you use the sizeof one member when declaring another member?

Tags: c++

Is this legal C++?

```
struct foo
{
  int a[100];
  int b[sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])];
};
```

GCC 4.6 accepts it, but MSVC 2012 doesn't. It seems like it should be fine to me, but a bit of Googling didn't help and I don't know where to look in the standard.

MSVC 2012 gives the following output:

```
error C2327: 'foo::a' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
error C2070: ''unknown-type'': illegal sizeof operand
warning C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I can't initialize non-const static member or static array in class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656941/why-i-cant-initialize-non-const-static-member-or-static-array-in-class)

Comment: Even if the ultimate cause is similar, the question looks very different to me.

Comment: The relevant paragraph in the C++11 standard is Clause 5, paragraph 8, I think.

Comment: @jrok: The relevant para is C++11 §12.6.2.8.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was illegal in C++03 because these members are nonstatic datamembers.

Starting from C++11 this is legal since in an unevaluated operand you can use nonstatic datamembers without having a corresponding object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: This is a workaround for MSVC 2010 and MSVC 2012

```
struct Aoo
{
    typedef int ArrayType;
    ArrayType a[100];
};

struct foo : public Aoo
{   
    enum {bSize = sizeof(Aoo) / sizeof(Aoo::ArrayType)};
    int b[bSize];
};
```