# is_function type trait for functors/function-objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, type-traits, most-vexing-parse

Consider the following piece of code:

```
struct Bar { 
  void operator()() {}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_function<Bar>::value << 
}
```

The output is `false`.

No surprises here since functor `Bar` does not qualify as a function type *§8.3.5 Functions [dcl.fct]*.

Now consider the following piece of code:

```
struct Bar { 
  void operator()() {}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_function<Bar()>::value << std::endl;
                                                     ^^
}
```

Notice the parentheses after `Bar`. The output is `true`.

How is `Bar()` qualified as a function type?

My guess is that it's a case of most vexing parse, but how can it be since it's in the template argument list?

Comment: If your objective is to see if `Bar` is callable (in some way), `std::is_function` isn't going to help.

Comment: @alfC yes my first impression was that I could query whether a type is callable. However, as I found out this is not its purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't think it is a MVP, it is simply the type of a function that returns `Bar` and does not take any arguments.

That is this function

```
Bar foo();
```

has type `Bar()`.

So naturally, `std::is_function<Bar()>::value` is `true`.

It would be the same that:

```
typedef Bar F();
std::cout << std::is_function<F>::value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Fair enough, but if it is/was so, shouldn't also `std::is_function<Bar(int, int)>::value` compile and be `true`?

Comment: @101010: Sure. Both GCC 5.2 and Clang++ 3.7 compile that and return `true`. If your compiler does not, I'd say it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Yeap you're right. Something else was meshing up my code.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that `Bar` is callable `std::is_function` doesn't help. To do that you need to do something else. Based on the general code (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18603716/225186):

```
template<class F, class... T, typename = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T>()...))> 
std::true_type  supports_test(const F&, const T&...);
std::false_type supports_test(...);

template<class> struct supports;
template<class F, class... T> struct supports<F(T...)> 
: decltype(supports_test(std::declval<F>(), std::declval<T>()...)){};
```

you can do

```
struct Bar { 
  void operator()() {}
  void operator()(double) {}
};

int main(){
    static_assert( supports<Bar()>::value == true , "");
    static_assert( supports<Bar(double)>::value == true , ""); // because of overload
    static_assert( supports<Bar(int)>::value == true , ""); // because of conversion
    static_assert( supports<Bar(std::string)>::value == false , "");
}
```